# How does one understand and make meaning of the Biein Melitz Yosher paragraph in the yom kippur shemone esreh?

Tags: tefilla, yom-kippur

How does one understand and make meaning of the Biein Melitz Yosher paragraph in the yom kippur shemone esreh ?

Comment: What bothers you about it? Is your question whether we literally have *no* defense counsel, or if it means "no *adequate* defense? I'd read it as the latter -- we are saying we don't feel like we have an adequate defense, and thus are relying on G-d's mercy.

Comment: Please [edit] in the text of the paragraph you reference and as best a translation as you can.

Comment: Any and all explanations of my question id appreciate answers explained.

Answer (score 2):

I found:

1] From [Chabad Moshe Bogomilsky](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2862658/jewish/What-Merit.htm)

"באין מליץ יושר מול מגיד פשע תגיד ליעקב דבר חוק ומשפט"
“When there is no defender to intercede in our behalf against the accuser who reports our transgression, You speak for Yaakov [and invoke the merit of the observance of] the statutes and ordinances.”

QUESTION: Precisely what merit do we ask Hashem to invoke in our behalf?

ANSWER: Many mitzvot of the Torah are in the category of “mishpatim” — “civil law and ordinances” — and others are “chukim” — “statutes.” Shofar is actually both, as the Psalmist says, “Blow shofar on the moon’s renewal...because chok l’Yisrael hu — it is a decree for Israel — mishpat l’Elokai Yaakov — a judgment for the G‑d of Yaakov (81:4-5).

Thus, we beseech Hashem, if there is no one to defend us against the accuser, then You should take over and tell him of Yaakov — the Jewish people — the great merit they have for just fulfilling devar chok u’mishpat — the mitzvah of shofar — which is both a statute and an ordinance.

2] From [Chabad of Cornell University](https://www.ithacamishpacha.org/blog/2021/10/1/nice-pshat-on-)

In the case of a Sanhedrim judging a case in which no member can speak positively for the accused then the accused goes free. That is to be applied to our situation – if there is no angel to speak for us  - אין מליץ יושר , then Hashem should  תגיד ליעקב דבר חוק ומשפט – tell Yaakov (= the Jewish people) the above principle and apply it and let us go free.

3] From [Rav A Y Kook end of Midbar Shur 9](https://www.sefaria.org/Midbar_Shur.9.5?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)

ביאור לד' הפיוט באין מליץ יושר מול מגיד פשע תגיד ליעקב דבר חק ומשפט וצדקנו במשפט". כי הנה במחצה זכיות ומחצה עונות אז '"רב חסד' מטה כלפי חסד", אמנם הזכיות והעונות כבר כ' הרמב"ם שאינם נשקלים כ"א בדעתו של אל דעות שיש מצוה א' שמכרעת נגד כמה עונות. והנה כשהקב"ה רוצה לעשות חסד עם ישראל אז הוא עושה חשבון שהעונות הם קלים מצד עצמם, דהיינו מפני האהבה שהקב"ה אוהב את ישראל, ודרך האוהב שחטא של אהובו הוא קל בעיניו. והנה האהבה היא בלא טעם אצלנו שאין אנו משיגים טעם אהבתו ית' לישראל, ומ"מ אחרי שמצד האהבה נחשב כל חטא לדבר קל, נמצא שאח"כ הזכיות מכריעות ונמצא שהזכות באה על פי דין ומשפט. וז"ש: "באין מליץ יושר" שישקול בערך "מול מגיד פשע", באופן שיהי' אפשר להיות רב חסד מטה כלפי חסד מצ"ע, ע"כ "תגיד ליעקב דבר חק" דהיינו אהבה בלא טעם, וממילא יקל משקל העונות ויהי' אח"כ "משפט", ועי"ז תצדקנו במשפט. וז"ש: "האוחז ביד מדת משפט", כי המדה איך ימוד המשפט, דהיינו ערכו של כל חטא, היא בידו ית', וכשהוא מראה גילוי האהבה, נעשה קל, והזכיות מכריעות.

We know that where sins and merits are equal Hashem inclines the scales of judgment towards kindness. Rambam teaches that only Hashem knows  the relative weights of the good and bad deeds. Hashem wants  to be kind to the Jewish people so He in His love will minimise the weight of the misdeeeds so that the merits will outweigh them. That's what the piyyut says, when there is no accuser to weigh the misdeeds heavily, ( באין מליץ יושר מול מגיד פשע) tell the Jews  תגיד ליעקב דבר חק something without reason ( חק) that is unreasoning love and then apply the judgment and through that we will be justified in judgment.

Answer (score 2):

The second cheilek (volume) of [Talelai Oros](https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%98%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%99-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%9B) on Rosh Hashanah (starting on page רלה) provides several explanations.

**1) Torah acts as a protection against the Satan**

> בְּאֵין מֵלִיץ יֽשֶׁר מוּל מַגִּיד פֶּֽשַׁע - When there is no one to plead [our] righteousness against the testimony of the accuser

This means that if G-d forbid there is no one who will positively guide us against the *kitrug* (the accusation/prosecution) of the Satan, then:

> תַּגִּיד לְיַעֲקֹב דְּבַר חֹק וּמִשְׁפָּט - Speak on behalf of Yaakov regarding the statute and law

This is a reference to the Torah and Kedusha (holiness). Like it says ([Tehillim 147:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.147.19?lang=bi)):

> מַגִּ֣יד דְּבָרָ֣ו לְיַעֲקֹ֑ב חֻקָּ֥יו וּ֝מִשְׁפָּטָ֗יו לְיִשְׂרָאֵֽל
>
> He issued His commands to Jacob, His statutes and rules to Israel.

And this means that the merit of Torah will protect Israel against the accusation of the Satan, like we say in [Sotah 21a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.21a.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that Torah is "מַגְּנָא וּמַצְּלָא" - "protects and saves".

The students of the Gra as per the sefer *Margalios HaTorah* add that the Gemara in [Bava Basra 16a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.16a.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes that the Satan descends and leads a person to sin, he then ascends and accuses. This is the meaning of how Torah is "מַגְּנָא", it first "protects" against the accusation of the Satan who descends and tries to tempt us to sin. Then Torah is "וּמַצְּלָא" in that it saves from the accusation, upon the Satan's return.

**2) The merit of Yaakov is our last line of defence**

It writes in [Shaarei Tzion](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=412&st=&pgnum=437&hilite=) (Left column 2nd paragraph) from [Rabbi Ben Zion Sternfeld, Av Beis Din of Bielsk](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj71OPz84SBAxU3VkEAHeNsDe0QFnoECBYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fshl2gur.tripod.com%2FChislavichi%2FSternfeld.htm&usg=AOvVaw25iyJe-X5dpsqpDF2KBOSf&opi=89978449) that when the prosecutor brings to trial a sin (חטא) that the person committed by mistake, there is an advocate that says that the sin was inadvertent. Similarly, if the person sins on purpose, but it was not to anger but merely to satisfy his desire, even still, there is an advocate that argues that his taavah (his overwhelming desire) caused him to sin and his heart was swayed accordingly.

But when the prosecutor brings to trial a rebellious sin (פשע) of the person, such as an offense that the person sinned to provoke, e.g. there's some meat of nevelah (i.e. a non-shechted carcass) before him and he eats it, in such a case there is no advocate who can plead and defend the man's act.

In such a case, this is what is meant by:

> בְּאֵין מֵלִיץ יֽשֶׁר מוּל מַגִּיד פֶּֽשַׁע - When there is no one to plead [our] righteousness against the testimony of the accuser

Namely, there is an opening here to exonerate the person in judgement. However,

> תַּגִּיד לְיַעֲקֹב דְּבַר חֹק וּמִשְׁפָּט - Speak on behalf of Yaakov regarding the statute and law

Meaning, that G-d promised Yaakov that He would save his sons in their time of trouble, even though they would have no right of their own at all, and that their salvation would come to them thanks to Yaakov Avinu. As it says in ([Tehillim 20:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.20.2?lang=bi)):

> יַֽעַנְךָ֣ יְ֭הֹוָה בְּי֣וֹם צָרָ֑ה יְ֝שַׂגֶּבְךָ֗ שֵׁ֤ם ׀ אֱלֹהֵ֬י יַעֲקֹֽב
>
> May the LORD answer you in time of trouble, the name of Jacob’s God keep you safe.

The [Shaarei Tzion](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=412&st=&pgnum=437&hilite=) (Left column 3rd paragraph) concludes that this is the explanation of the piyut we say on the first day of Rosh Hashanah:

> ואם יצאה גזירה דחוקה ומבולקה, לחבל את כל יושבי ארקא תביט בתבנית אשר בכסא חקוקה
>
> If a pressing and destructive decree is issued, to bind all dwellers of earth, look at the shape of the carved throne.

In other words, the image of Yaakov is engraved on G-d's Kisei HaKavod (heavenly throne) and by gazing at it, it will trigger the memory of Yaakov who Hashem promised would keep his children safe in his merit.

**3) The measure-for-measure insurance policy**

The Drashos Chasam Sofer explains that only a few of our prayers are intentional but most are unintentional. The Satan thus comes and prosecutes against all those prayers that came out unintentionally. So instead of being helpful, these tefillos actually prove harmful.

As Jews we must observe the mitzvos and laws i.e. those that have logic, as if they were chukim, which are without reason and understanding, simply because Hashem commanded so. And on the other hand, the chukim of the Torah must be observed as if they were intellectually understandable. So much so, that it would be as despicable and abominable for a person to wear/plant kilayim as if he were killing someone or eating bugs.

If we act like this, then Hashem acts measure for measure, and He accepts the prayers that lack concentration etc. as if they were uttered with complete and overflowing intent.

This is what it means:

> בְּאֵין מֵלִיץ יֽשֶׁר מוּל מַגִּיד פֶּֽשַׁע - When there is no one to plead [our] righteousness against the testimony of the accuser

i.e. If a person is not focused on their prayer and does not pray with heartfelt intent, the Satan will prosecute accordingly and retell their sins, and there is no one who will do good for them.

And yet,

> תַּגִּיד לְיַעֲקֹב דְּבַר חֹק וּמִשְׁפָּט - Speak on behalf of Yaakov regarding the statute and law

i.e. the chok (the statute) will be in their eyes like a mishpat (a law) and vice versa, and thus it is guaranteed that...

> וְצַדְּקֵֽנוּ בַּמִּשְׁפָּט - And make us righteous with justice

i.e. Hashem will resultantly view us in a positive light - measure for measure

A similar approach is taken by the Chavos Yair and Rabbi Elazar Kalir...

The [Yalkut Shimoni on Yechezkel](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.702.8?vhe=Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach&lang=bi) writes:

> שאלו לחכמה חוטא מה עונשו, א"ל חטאים תרדף רעה, שאלו לנבואה חוטא מה עונשו א"ל הנפש החוטאת היא תמות. שאלו לתורה חוטא מה עונשו א"ל (סה) יביא אשם ויתכפר לו. שאלו להקב"ה חוטא מה עונשו, א"ל יעשה תשובה ויתכפר לו
>
> They asked wisdom - what is a sinner's punishment? He said, sins will pursue evil. The asked prophecy - what is a sinner's punishment? He said, the soul that sins will die. They asked Torah - what is a sinner's punishment? He said, he should bring a guilt offering and it will atone for him. They asked Hashem - what is a sinner's punishment? He said he will do Teshuva and that will repent for him.

The whole foundation of teshuvah is a great innovation, because according to the intelligent, teshuvah does not help, and as they said by wisdom and prophecy, there is no remedy for sin. Indeed, it is the way of the world that when a person rebels against a king, his ruling is to die and all his pleas and expressions of remorse will not be of any use.

And yet, the power of teshuva is given only to Israel and not to the other nations of the world. This is due to the premise of measure-for-measure. Just as Jews fulfill the mitzvos of Hashem, so too they fulfill chukim for which they don't know the reason. Similarly, G-d provided Teshuva which is like a chok, in that it helps without any reason.

This is why it says "מַגִּ֣יד דְּבָרָ֣ו לְיַעֲקֹ֑ב" as Hashem provides the Jews with this medium of repentance which allows them to be atoned simply because "חֻקָּ֥יו וּ֝מִשְׁפָּטָ֗יו לְיִשְׂרָאֵֽל" - that they keep the statutes and laws as one, and they don't discern between knowing the reason and not. Thus, "לֹ֘א עָ֤שָׂה כֵ֨ן ׀ לְכׇל־גּ֗וֹי" ("He did not do so for any other nation") - the non-Jews don't have these statues and are only commanded on matters that are intellectually comprehensible.

(In addition refer to [Bnei Yissascher](https://www.sefaria.org/Bnei_Yissaschar%2C_Kislev_and_Tevet.4.62.4?vhe=Bnei_Yisaschar,_Piotrkow_1883&lang=bi) and also note the [Ozharover Rebbe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Yechiel_Epstein) in his Be'er Moshe on Parshas Mishpatim which brings the custom of the Maharil to say "[וצדקנו במשפט המלך המשפט - האוחז ביד מדת משפט](https://www.sefaria.org/Machzor_Rosh_Hashanah_Ashkenaz%2C_Musaf%2C_First_Day_of_Rosh_Hashana%2C_Kedushah.14-15?vhe=The_Metsudah_Machzor._Metsudah_Publications,_New_York_--_he_(paragraph_ed.)&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)" all in one breath which hints at the fact that despite Hashem acting as the King of judgement, it is nevertheless done with the "middas" - "the attribute" of judgment - a play on words alluding to מדה כנגד מדה).